# Вычисление функции разложением в ряд Тейлора

Tags: python, ряды

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему с вычислением функций разложением в ряд Тейлора. Первый столбец отвечает за значения аргумента, второй столбец за значения функции в точке. Третий столбец с неверными числами: там должны быть более точные значения функции (примерно равные числам со второго столбца), так как они вычисляются разложением функции в ряд Тейлора.

Вообще вот у меня задача стоит есть подынтегральная функция и разложить ее в ряд и вычислить приближенно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import math
def f(x):
    return 1 / (math.sqrt(1 - x ** 4))


def test(x, eps):
    sum = 1
    n = 4
    t = 1
    while t * t > eps * eps:
        t += 1 / 4 * math.factorial(-2 + n) * (1 / (math.sqrt(math.pi) * math.factorial(n / 4))) * x ** n
        print(t)
        n += 1
        sum += t
    return sum


a = 0.5
b = 0.6
eps = 0.00001

print("  xi | f(xi)")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
while a < b:
    if a != 0.5:
        print("", round(a, 5), "|", round(f(a), 5), round(test(a, eps), 5))
    else:
        print(round(a, 5), "|", round(f(a), 5), round(test(a, eps), 5))
    a += 0.1
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

Формула которую выдает вольфрамальфа при разложение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю, но мало ли вдруг поможет.Вот например я так реализовывал один из интегралов на матлабе.Может и на пайтоне есть библиотека которая бы все упростила?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Также то что должно получится приближенно 0.1050208650082836 
Оценка абсолютной погрешности: 
1.165965823982469*1е-15

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+series+1%2Fsqrt%281-x%5E4%29+at+x%3D0

Comment: В функции тест у вас даже не участвует икс

Comment: Да вы правы там нужно дописать x**n не внимательность

Comment: Не ясно зачем тут numpy

Comment: Вы  уверены, что формула верна t * = 1.0 / ( m1.sqrt(m1.pi) * m1.pi) * (-2+n) * x**n - это после упрощения. Смущает корень из пи умножить на пи

Comment: Точно а вы правы!!! там n/4.
Правда с калькулятором всю равно не сходится

Comment: Вы ещё раз формулу напишите в вопросе, которая у Вас получилась при разложении в ряд. Просто я что-то не припомню в рядах Тейлора корни из пи. Там степени и факториалы вроде

Comment: Так там у Вас же Факториалы должны быть! Факториал числителя и в знаменателе n/4 факториал и сумма с t а не произведение

Comment: Cделал как вы сказали и получаю следующую ошибку:
in test t += 1 / 4 * math.factorial(-2 + n) * (1 / (math.sqrt(np.pi) * math.factorial(n / 4))) * x ** n
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
Это при n = 4

Comment: А можно как-то увидеть ряд Тейлора с большим количеством элементов 1+ x**4/2...

Comment: Я обновил
Но в случае чего вы можете перейти на сайт https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+series+1%2Fsqrt%281-x%5E4%29+at+x%3D0
И там нажать More terms и Вам будут выдавать еще большего порядка разложения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция :

```
def test(x, eps):

    sum_total = 0 
    n = 0
    t = 1.0
    eps2 = eps * eps
    while t * t > eps2:
        tt =  m1.gamma((n-2) / 4 + 1) / ( m1.sqrt(m1.pi) * m1.factorial(n//4) ) * x**n
        t *= tt
        n += 4
        sum_total += tt
    return sum_total
```

Результат:

```
  xi | f(xi)
----------------------------
0.5 | 1.0328 1.03279
0.51 | 1.03565 1.03564
0.52 | 1.03869 1.03868
0.53 | 1.04195 1.04194
----------------------------
```

Comment: Да, но если вогнать https://www.integral-calculator.ru/  сюда то получаем следующий результат: 
в приближении:
0.1050208650082836.
Заметка: Приближение было получено с помощью Численного интегрирования. Оценка абсолютной погрешности: 
1.165965823982469*1e-5

Comment: Или вольфрамальфа неправильно раскладывает или код не правильный у меня...

Comment: Я видел этот сайт и данные - я не совсем понял, что там имеется ввиду, но функция начинается от 1 по У. Подставим Х=0 и получаем 1

Comment: Ага понял.Смотрите я скорее всего неправильно формулировал условие в вольфрамальфа.Не знаю
точно пока что буду разбираться.
Но если перейти сюда https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2Csqrt%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C4%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0.5%2C0.6%7D%5D
Увидем что совпадает все с предыдущим сайтом.

Comment: Ну тогда ставьте как ответ и закрываем вопрос:)

Comment: Я кое-что обновил.Скажите есть ли  пайтон библиотека вроде функции taylor как в матлабе, может кто-то знает?

Comment: Я не встречал, только визуализация (графики)

Comment: Ок.Спасибо на этом!